# Pull html code of website as php variable

Tags: php, curl

I have several hundred websites that I need to search for a phone number, I would like to use PHP to search for me, and if I could just figure out how to grab a webpage and set the entire html of that page as a variable, I could write a script that goes through all websites and does a search for the string I need to find..

What can I do with php so I can use

```
echo $url
```

and i will see the html code of a website, not the page rendered?

Everything I have tried with curl rendered the page when I executed.
Thank you!

Comment: php does not render anything but if you echo to the browser, yes, you will see the rendered version in the browser.

Comment: If you try to output string contents that contain HTML to a browser screen, most likely it is going to render as HTML.  Why would you output all the contents anyway if you are just searching for some content within the page? This seem like more of a problem to solve with DOMDocument/DOMXPath or similar.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php
    $html = file_get_contents( $url );

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
htmlspecialchars($data);
```

From the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php):

```
$new = htmlspecialchars("<a href='test'>Test</a>", ENT_QUOTES);
echo $new; // &lt;a href=&#039;test&#039;&gt;Test&lt;/a&gt;
```

As to search in the variable (`$new` in this case), you should use regular expressions. But be careful, displaying the html as markup instead of rendering it, will show the code on a website, but you do **not** need to do this to search in the string.

The string (the source) is perfectly fine after the `curl` or `file_get_contents` method.

Also for, parsing the html, I find [PHP Simple HTML DOM parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) to be incredible offering selectors and lots of utilities that, depending on your case may be better.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the htmlentities function [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) function to convert html tags to text.

```
echo htmlentities($page_content);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [file() function in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) to grab the raw HTML. They even demonstrate this in the first example.

Answer (score 0):

This [link](http://davidwalsh.name/curl-download) has a pretty good example:

```
/* gets the data from a URL */
function get_data($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 5;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}

$returned_content = get_data('http://stackoverflow.com');
```

You can then use regex on `$returned_content` to find the string that you are looking for.